# Настройка Xdebug + PhpStorm + PHP-fpm + Ubuntu

Tags: php, nginx, phpstorm, php-fpm, xdebug

Не получается настроить Xdebug.

Lелаю так:
В файле 
/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/php.ini

Прописываю следующие параметры

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so 
; остальные обязательные параметры
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=10
xdebug.max_nesting_level=20000000
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

Затем выполняю команды

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
```

Настраиваю IDE
Следую вот этой инструкции 
https://gist.github.com/me7media/6291827bb44b7e90e905ff8bdda8182e

Потом ставлю точки останова, устанавливаю на прослушку, но ничего не происходит - скрипт не останавливается и текущие значения переменных не выводятся.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы включили ваш модуль через phpenmod для PHP? Эти конфигурационные данные что вы написали должны идти и в CLI (если вам понадобится отладка из под консоли), и в веб конфигурации (FPM) php.ini. Проверяйте если модуль успешно загружен через “php -m”

Comment: Да, конечно, я проверял, там после включения расширения этот модуль добавился.

Comment: В таком случае рекомендую проверить в самом PHPStorm что он показывает что расширение включено и работет в File => Settings => Languages & Frameworks => PHP => CLI Interpreters. Так же проверьте что вы поставили IDE ключ как указано в вашем конф. файле (PHPSTORM) при создании PHP Remote Debug. Учтите что нужно создавать новую конфигурацию через Run => Edit Configurations => Add New Configuration, а не редактировать ту, что в Templates.

Comment: Сейчас всё перепроверил, сейчас получается так: включаю прослушивание и дебаг, ставлю точку останова на index.php (вначале), выполнение останавливается, вижу переменные POST, GET и т.д. (локальных не вижу). Жму F8  и всё как бы сбрасывается - деббагер прекращает работу

Comment: В вашем случае нужно настроить Path Mapping в Server (Run => Debug Configurations => Server) - если у вас его нет, то нужно создать, задать домен и настроить [маппинг файлов сервера на локальные файлы](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-remote-interpreters.html). Также мне **кажется** что нужно не просто ставить на прослушку, а запускать веб-проект через Run => Debug => Ваша Remote PHP Debug конфигурация.

Comment: А в Path Mapping что нужно указать? Сейчас там так: Project files - /var/www/GIF/gif-api и Absolute path on server  - /var/www/GIF/gif-api

Comment: то есть пути одни и те же

Comment: Если пути одинаковы - тогда не нужно, @Rumato.